# Are there any omni directional stereo mics for camcorders

Tags: audio, microphone

I am looking for a good microphone to film trains as they go by.

I have been looking, at the Opteka VM-200. But I am concerned that the shotgun directional characteristic will not work well, since I want to pick up the sound of the train coming in the distance.

But it seems like almost all camcorder external microphones are shotgun and directional, and quite commonly mono.

To make things even more confusing, I am looking for a low frequency response, to capture the rumbling low end.

In addition, it needs to fit a wind sock on it.

But most importantly, right now it are there any that are omni directional. I can't find one!!

Comment: I have the Azden SMX-30 and I love it! Both stereo (Omni-directional) and mono (directional). Comes with a wind cover, and Azden's add-on dead cat (furry windshield) isn't super expensive. It isn't cheap (the total cost is $280 from Azden), but the rave reviews on Amazon might help you decide. I went to a store and tried various Sennheiser and Rode mics, but this mic was the best I tried. Good luck hunting!

Comment: Boy, that's a list. I'm thinking you might need multiple mics, then you'd have to mix in post to get the sound your looking for.